# Post query string direct to httpHandler by java

Tags: java, http-post, httphandler

I have a http handler locate at:

```
http://localhost:8118/log.srv
```

When i paste this url on IE, it's work well.

```
http://localhost:8118/log.srv?action=likearticle&noname=989858&ladoi=cutymaraton
```

The http handler got data.

But when i use java program to post data, no error occur, but, the http handler not get any data.
My java program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for(int i=1; i<1000; i++){
                URL url= new URL("http://localhost:8118/log.srv");
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                String data = "action=likearticle&noname=989858&ladoi=cutymaraton"+i;
                System.out.println(data);
                writer.write(data);
                writer.flush();
            }

            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I use another code:

```
String urlParameters = "action=likearticle&noname=989858&ladoi=cutymaraton";
            String request = "http://localhost:8118/log.srv";
            URL url = new URL(request); 
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setUseCaches (false);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            connection.disconnect();
```

No error, but not successful sending data.
Show me why? and any solution for that?

Comment: Why don't you add the parameters as query parameters like you in the browser?

Comment: @Tichodroma: How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [more friendly](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html) API, like this:

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://localhost:8118/log.srv");
post.setRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
NameValuePair[] data = {
  new NameValuePair("action", "likearticle"),
  new NameValuePair("noname", "989858"),
  new NameValuePair("ladoi", "cutymaraton")
};
post.setRequestBody(data);    

HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);

InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
// handle response.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the URL with query parameter.

```
URL url= new URL("http://localhost:8118/log.srv?action=likearticle&noname=989858&ladoi=cutymaraton"+i);
```

Comment: yeb, i use: `URL url1= new URL("http://10.5.5.71:8118/log.srv?action=likearticle&noname=989858&ladoi=cutymaraton");
   url1.openConnection();` But not done.